# Apply regex filter for string which returns the value after occurrence of the given character in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to build a PowerShell script which returns the phrase after the first occurrence of a given character in a string. E.g i want to get all the phrases after the first occurrence of the `v` character:

```
blah_v1.2
foo_v1
vbarv_2.4
bar
```

The result would be

```
1.2
1
barv_2.4
```

I've tried to build something like this, but the $FooVersion returns a boolean instead of a string.

```
$Foo = "blah_v1.1"
$FooVersion = $Foo -match "_v (.*)"

Write-Host $Foo
Write-Host $FooVersion
```

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out some possibilities:

```
$Foo = "blah_v1.1"

# using -replace
# returns a string without 'v' as-is
$FooVersion = $Foo -replace '(?:[^v]*v)(.*)', '$1'
```

or

```
# using -split at the first 'v' character
# returns a string without 'v' as-is; use [1] to return '' instead
$FooVersion = ($Foo -split 'v', 2)[-1]
```

or

```
# using -match
# returns $null for a string without 'v'; add `else { $Foo }` to return it as-is
$FooVersion = if ($Foo -match 'v(.*)') { $Matches[1] }

Write-Host $Foo
Write-Host $FooVersion
```

Comment: @mklement0 (+1) for [your detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53853123/9898643). Finally I'm getting the meaning of `*?` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you look for everything that isn't a `v` and then the first v, then grab the captured value from the `$Matches` variable:

```
$strings = -split @'
blah_v1.2
foo_v1
vbarv_2.4
bar
'@

$strings |ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '[^v]*v(.*)'){
        $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; you can simplify the regex somewhat to `v(.*)` (the greediness of `.*` will ensure that only the _first_ `v` is matched).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) with an array of input strings allows for a concise solution:

```
# Sample input lines (string array)
$lines = @'
blah_v1.2
foo_v1
vbarv_2.4
bar
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Perform a regex-based string replacement on each input line,
# so as to only extract the substrings of interest.
$lines -replace '.*?v(.*)', '$1'
```

The above yields:

```
1.2
1
barv_2.4
bar
```

Given an *array* as the LHS, `-replace` operates on the array's elements one by one.

Regex `.*?v(.*)` non-greedily (`?`) matches anything (`.*`) up to the *first* `v`, then (greedily) captures anything after the `v` in a capture group (`(...)`), `$1` in the replacement operand refers to that capture group, and since the regex matched the entire input string, the output is whatever came after the first `v` in the input.

Note that **`-replace` passes input that doesn't match the regex through as-is**, which is why `bar`, which doesn't contain a `v`, is also present in the output; if you wanted to ***omit* lines without a `v`**, as in your sample output:

```
@($lines) -match 'v' -replace '.*?v(.*)', '$1'
```

Note the `@(...)` around `$lines`, which ensures that the LHS is always considered an *array*, because `-match` only acts as a filter with an array-valued LHS, not with a single input string (see below).
(The sample input above is by definition an array, but if you load your lines from a file with `Get-Content`, for instance, a single-line input file would result in a *single string*, not in a 1-element array.)

`-match 'v'` therefore returns the sub-array of `$line` elements that contain the letter `v`, which `-replace` then operates on.

Note:

- The array + `-replace` approach is convenient and fast for collections that are already *in memory*.

  - If you need to perform the replacement in a *pipeline*, use [Mathias R. Jessen's `ForEach-Object`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53851466/45375).
- That said, if you know that your input set can fit into memory as a whole, you can improve performance by capturing pipeline (cmdlet) output in an expression (`(...)` or, to guarantee an array, `@(...)`) to which `-replace` can again be applied:
  `@(Get-Content input.txt) -replace '.*?v(.*)', '$1'`

---

As for **what you tried**:

With a *scalar* LHS, `-match` returns a *Boolean* (indicating whether the input matched or not), as you've experienced.

However, with a *scalar* LHS (only!), PowerShell populates the automatic `$Matches` hashtable with detailed information about the match ((sub)string that matched (entry `0`), capture-group values (entry `1` for the 1st capture group, ...)), so you can use that *afterwards*, as demonstrated in [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53851466/45375).