# Apply a filter for string which contains given phrase and return everything which occurs after

Tags: powershell

I want to build a PowerShell script which returns everything which occurs after the occurrence of the given string. I want to run a command against a single string instead of a collection.

E.g. I want to return everything after the phrase "_blah_"

```
_blah_v2.3 
_blah_bar_blah_v56
_blah_v42 
foo
```

Result:

```
v2.3 
bar_blah_v56
v42
```

Probably Regex would be too heavy for such operation so looking for some alternative solution 
I've tried this:

```
$Foo = "blah_v1.1"
$FooVersion = ($Foo -split '_blah_', 2)[1]

Write-Host $Foo
Write-Host $FooVersion
```

but it works only with a single character instead of a string. I'm not fluent in PowerShell and looking for some quick and handy solution.

Comment: `"_blah_bar_blah_v56" -replace "^.*?blah_"`? or something similar. Regex seems perfect for something like this. replace from the start of the string until and including the "word"

Comment: The only problem with your `-split` command (which uses a regex too, by the way) is that you're only matching `_blah_`, whereas the input has only `blah_`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Probably Regex would be too heavy for such operation

No, it wouldn't.

```
"_blah_v2.3" -replace '^.*?_blah_'
```

Comment: Or use matches with positive lookbehind: `(?<=blah_)` if they don't need a replace action.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That might react funny if `blah` occurs a second time in the middle of the word, like in the OP's second example.

Comment: Using `-match` would still require a second operation. The replace... depending how its used... would not ruin anything.

Answer (score 1):

So the string with the given phrase differs from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851150/apply-regex-filter-for-string-which-returns-the-value-after-occurrence-of-the-gi), but for the rest there is not much difference.

Use something like

```
$FooVersion = $Foo -replace '_?blah_(.*)', '$1'
```

or

```
$FooVersion = ($Foo -split '_?blah_', 2)[-1]
```

or

```
if ($Foo -match '_?blah_(.*)') { $FooVersion = $Matches[1] } else { $FooVersion = $Foo }
```

would do it.

Please also read the explanation given by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53853123/9898643). That will surely help in future cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unless performance is critical (extremely rare), regex is nice. I would use positive lookbehind. See following example:

```
$test = '_blah_v2.3 ','_blah_bar_blah_v56','blah_v42 ','foo'
($test | Select-String '(?<=blah_).*').Matches.Value
```

Note that I used `blah_` as separator.